# Не работает кнопка в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю модель самолета на С#, Unity.

Хочу добавить кнопку, при клике на которую увеличивается параметр мощности в пять раз.

На данный момент создала кнопку, привязала к ней функцию. Пыталась вывести хотя бы сообщение в консоль при клике на нее, но ничего не получилось(

Подскажите еще пожалуйста правильно ли я импортировала класс во втором файле?

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using AircraftSimulator;

namespace AircraftSimulator {
    public class Forsage : MonoBehaviour {
        public bool forsage;     
        public void ButtonForsage( )
        {
            forsage = true;
            Console.WriteLine("111");
            Console.ReadKey() ;
        }

    }

}
```

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using static AircraftSimulator.Forsage;

namespace AircraftSimulator {
    public class Engine : Component {
        private double _currentPower;
        AircraftSimulator.Forsage Forsage = new AircraftSimulator.Forsage();
        public Engine(double mass, string name, Vector3 relativePosition, double maxPower = 100) {
            _currentPower = 0;
            MaxPower = 400;
            Mass = mass;
            Name = name;
            RelativePosition = relativePosition;
        }
        public double CurrentPower {
            get => _currentPower;

            set {
                if (Forsage.forsage)  {
                    _currentPower = 5 * Math.Max(Math.Min(MaxPower, value), 0);
                }
                else {
                    _currentPower = Math.Max(Math.Min(MaxPower, value), 0);
                }
            }
        }
    public double MaxPower { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `using static` используется для импорта статических членов и констант класса, в `AircraftSimulator.Forsage` таких нет, и даже обычная дирeктива `using` там не нужна, так как классы находятся в одном неймспейсе

Comment: К слову непонятно разбиение вашей логики на несколько классов. И наследование `Engine` от `Component`. И если хотите чтобы значение приватного поля сохранялось, нужно пометить его аттрибутом `[SerializeField]`.

Comment: Спасибо, а я в таком случае правильно обращаюсь к классу Forsage и к переменной forsage?

Comment: Правильно, но вот только ваш код должен быть понятен людям, которые возможно буду его читать. Поэтмоу bool переменные обычно называют начиная с is или do или has и так далее. Совершенно не понятно за что отвечает переменная forsage в классе с ТЕМ ЖЕ названием, особенно учитывая, что такого слова в английском нет (хотя есть такая компания, это точно то, что вам нужно?)

Comment: А это UI или что-то другое?

Comment: @mksmptrnk это UI

Comment: А на сцене стоит event system?

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите, увидеть что-то в консоли unity, пишите туда `Debug.Log("111");`.

> Math.Max(Math.Min(max, value), min);

Для этого есть clamp:

```
Mathf.Clamp(value, min, max);
```

`double` обычно не испольуют, нет нужды в такой точности, `float`.

Импортируешь не правильно:

1. `static`?
2. только `using AircraftSimulator;`, без `.Forsage`
3. твой код и так уже внутри этого неймспейса, без всяких `using`.

Не пользуйся неймспейсами.

Comment: Спасибо, а я в таком случае правильно обращаюсь к классу Forsage и к переменной forsage?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вы хотите что-то типа такого. Ещё лучше будет хранить не флаг вашего "ускорения", а его модификатор, равный 1 при нормальных условиях. Не знаю как сейчас, но раньше у юнити были проблемы с не-автосвойствами и ваши геттеры и сеттеры вряд ли отработали, поэтому для настройки из инспектора лучше воспользоваться полем.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace AircraftSimulator
{
    public class Engine : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private const float MaxPower = 400; // Ваше значение

        [Range(0, MaxPower)]
        [SerializeField]
        private float _currentPower;
        private bool forsage;

        public void ButtonForsage()
        {
            forsage = true;
        }

        public double CurrentPower
        {
            get => _currentPower * (forsage ? 5 : 1);
            set => _currentPower = Math.Clamp(value, 0, MaxPower);
        }
    }
}
```